# Spring events for games.. can it handle it?

Tags: spring, spring-3

Im looking at implementing a tablet game, and am considering various solutions for the gaming server side of things.

The game basically loops through a set of states, which trigger message events to be sent to clients. Message sending is done via another API. So the event listener delegates to the message sender on a particular event.

Another listener handles the incoming parts, but im only concerned with sending raising events on state changes.

I have looked at JMS and Spring events, i like spring events as they are neat and tidy, however not sure how they would cope on a server. JMS seems large and since im only listeneing to internal events most of the time, not sure how they would work if things changed.. hummm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speaking of spring, you could like the AspectJ. Aspect-oriented way of handling events is described in a pretty nice way in "Spring in Action" book.
Spring AOP could help you.

Comment: for events?... im not convinced.. but il look into it.. heard AOP being used for security interception..

Comment: You could actually make, like it is done in my project (I have to use JMS + Spring). We have covered the events with the "joint points" in AOP and the AOP-advices are called from there. I am not telling this is a good solution, but still you could try.